# JQuery/Javascript on click not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone explaine to me why my javascript is not working. I am trying the set the value of a hidden field on my site. The script have worked but for som reason it is not working anymore.

 Here is the javascript

```
<script>
    $('#checkDk').on('change', function () {
        $('#MainContent_hiddenTargetDk').val($(this).prop("checked") ? $(this).val() : "");
        console.log($("#MainContent_hiddenTargetDk").val());
    });
</script>
```

Here is the button.

```
<label runat="server" id="dk" class="btn btn-default">
    <input runat="server" id="checkDk" type="checkbox" value="208" onselect="getvalue()" autocomplete="off">
    Denmark
</label>
```

And here is the hiddenfield:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenTargetDk" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(#hiddenTargetDk)` not`$(#MainContent_hiddenTargetDk)`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenTargetDk" runat="server" />
<label runat="server" id="dk" class="btn btn-default">
                            <input runat="server" id="checkDk" type="checkbox" value="208" onselect="getvalue()" autocomplete="off">
                            Denmark
                        </label>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
    $('#checkDk').on('change', function () {
        $('#hiddenTargetDk').val($(this).prop("checked") ? $(this).val() : "");
        console.log($("#hiddenTargetDk").val());
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Right, ok down voter, I'd love to know the reason why my answer is wrong? It's a simple mismatch of id. It's safe to assume you have an agenda. Unless you have 5 multiple accounts, you can't even slow me down with 2 points at a time, do the math.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the value to the `input` hidden using its `id` which is `#hiddenTargetDk` not `#MainContent_hiddenTargetDk`

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/cn6zcfy1/)**

**jQuery:**

```
$('#checkDk').on('change', function () {

        $('#hiddenTargetDk').val($(this).prop("checked") ? $(this).val() : "");
        console.log($("#hiddenTargetDk").val());
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

You're binding to a `changed` event and waiting for it on a `click`. I do think this is not how it's supposed to work.

Try this instead:

```
 $('#checkDk').on('click', function () {
    $('#MainContent_hiddenTargetDk').val($(this).prop("checked") ? $(this).val() : "");
    console.log($("#MainContent_hiddenTargetDk").val());
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is a combination of the other answers, and a secret back-end quirk with ASP.NET.

ASP.NET is changing the ID of your hidden field.  You need to add the ClientIDMode="Static" property to your fields you want to use JQuery with like this:

```
<label runat="server" id="dk" class="btn btn-default">
    <input runat="server" id="checkDk" type="checkbox" value="208" onselect="getvalue()" autocomplete="off" clientidmode="static">
    Denmark
</label>

<input type="hidden" id="hiddenTargetDk" runat="server" clientidmode="static" />
```

Then you can identify your objects using JQuery by simply:

```
$('#checkDK')
```

and

```
$('#hiddenTargetDK')
```

I would write the JQuery like this I suppose:

```
<script>
    $('#checkDk').click(function () {
        $('#hiddenTargetDk').val($(this).prop("checked") ? $(this).val() : "");
        console.log($("#hiddenTargetDk").val());
    });
</script>
```

This feature was added to .NET 4.0 and after I believe.  The .NET framework renames the IDs of all objects with the runat="server" property on them, and IIS, IIS Express, and each different version/configuration of IIS may rename them differently, which is why your code broke.  Setting the client ID mode to static ensures that ASP.NET does not rename your IDs, but rather uses another field to hold it's "True name".  Good luck out there!

Comment: Who downvoted me? -_- I guarantee this is the correct answer.  I recognize the ASP.NET syntax, his original band-aid, why it broke, and how to fix it the right way.